# Trying to select the max amount of unique occurrences

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to list the first and last name of employees working on projects with the greatest number of unique project locations.

```
Select distinct Fname
     , Lname 
  from employee a 
  join project b 
  join works_on c
where a.Ssn = c.Essn 
   and b.Pnumber = c.Pno
group by Fname
     , Lname
order by Fname desc
     , Lname desc
     , COUNT(Plocation) desc;
```

and it returns:

```
Fname   |  Lname
-----------------
Ramesh    Narayan
Joyce     English
John      Smith
Jennifer  Wallace
James     Borg
Franklin  Wong
Alicia    Zelaya
Ahmad     Jabbar
```

but I want to eliminate John Smith and Joyce English as they are not apart of the projects that have the most unique locations. All of the rest should be there. I tried using  `having max(count)` but this did not work.

EDIT: Sorry, I'm very new to sql and stackoverflow. I apoligize if this is too much or too little to be adding but here is a fiddle of the tables I am using and their inputs:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=431df290c2042d46ba44a20c34a0c7b1

These are the First names and Last Names I should be getting because they are apart of projects that are in locations: `Stafford` and `Houston` which have the most occurrences in projects of 2.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  It is quite unclear how you know which projects have the most locations.  Also learn to use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Sorry about that, I have edited the post to add my CREATE and INSERT statements. Hope that helps and thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Based on the query, how do you know that `Joyce English` and `John Smith` should be excluded? If you need to use the fiddle I've edited into your question; edit the queries etc., click 'run' and it will generate a new fiddle link. Copy the new updated link into your question if necessary.

Comment: According to your data model, a project has only one location.  I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the analytical function `RANK`, create sub-query and join with your existing query as follows:

```
Select distinct Fname , Lname 
  from employee e 
  join works_on w on e.ssn = w.essn
  join project p on p.Pnumber = w.Pno
  join (select plocation, rank() over (order by count(1) desc) as rn
          from project
        group by plocation) max_location 
    on max_location.plocation = p.plocation and max_location.rn = 1
```

<kbd>[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0b855406b58aafa8bbf748b2dfe3f512)</kbd>

**Note:** Always use the standard `ANSI` joins